# Design pattern for executing dependent methods in a class

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class in which I have to repeat multiple steps to complete a process like below, this is just a pseudo code to demonstrate what I am asking. Basically each method needs another method to do something, so a few methods are executed one after another to get the desired result, but somehow I don't like this, is there another way to achieve this may be using a design pattern? I have seen the chain of responsibility but that does not suit me as I don't have different type of processors.

Thanks

```
class Processor
{
    void Process()
    {
        var credentials = GetCredentialsFromDb();

        var result = ProcessData(credentials);
    }

    string GetCredentialsFromDb()
    {
        return "user";
    }

    string ProcessData(string credentials)
    {
        return ExtractData();
    }

    string ExtractData()
    {
        return ParseData();
    }

    string ParseData()
    {
        return ValidateData(data);
    }

    string ValidateData(string data)
    {
        return "validatedData";
    }
}
```

Comment: That whole design seems fine, you could use `Template` if you are going to derive/override those methods and want to *always* call them all in turn.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a Builder Pattern - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Basically the `builder` initializes your object and contains all of the logic, each in separate methods taking arguments for what information they need, for "building up" the end result.

Then you would implement a `director` that always calls them in sequence.

```
public static void main() {
    var builder = new ProcessorBuilder();
    ProcessorDirector director = new ProcessorDirector();
    director.Build();
    Console.WriteLine(builder.Processor);
}

class ProcessorDirector { //I tell processor builders how to build processors!
    ProcessorBuilder _builder {get;private set;}
    public ProcessorDirector(ProcessorBuilder builder) {
        _builder = builder;
    }
    public void Build() {
        var credentials = _builder.GetCredentialsFromDB();
        var data = _builder.ProcessData(credentials);
        var isDataValid = _builder.ValidateData();
        if(isDataValid) {
             _builder.ParseData();
        }
    }
}
class ProcessorBuilder
{
    public string Processor {get;set;}
    void ProcessorBuilder()
    {
        //if you change your end result object into a non-value type, you'd initialize it here.
    }
    public string GetCredentialsFromDb()
    {
        return "user";
    }
    string ProcessData(string credentials)
    {
        //process
        //builder should be stateless, so return data
    }
    public string ParseData()
    {
        //parse
    }
    public string ValidateData()
    {
        //validate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As each of your method calls wraps around the subsequent one, I'd say that the decorator pattern could fit your needs.

This would allow you to specify how the stack is build by only accepting certain types to be wrapped in others, if this is important.